# Best Practice around Geocoding?

Tags: sql-server-2008, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

Can anyone weigh in on best practice around geocoding location data?

We have several hundred "locations" (and growing) that are regularly inserted into the database.

We will occassionally run queries to plop these on a Google Maps using the Javascript API.

Do you think it's better to geocode these addresses when they're inserted into the database (ie, add lng and lat fields and populate and store these--addresses won't be modified manually) or call a geocoding service whenever we are generating our maps?

Comment: See [this discussion of geocoding strategies](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat) from the Google Maps API v3 documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing the long/lat values will be much faster when it comes to use them. As long as you're happy they wont be moving around on their own between data entry and map drawing then do that.

Answer (score 0):

We call the geocoding api and store the latitude/longitude upon insert of a new record or update of any address field.  Not only is this quicker when adding the location to a map, but it reduces repeated calls to the API.  Given that there is a limit to the number of calls you may make in a day (enforced as calls per second) you don't want to do it any more than you have to.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the geocodes (but updating them occasionally) is a recommended best practice by Google.